# Django ORM: filter related objects?

Tags: python, django

Assuming I have a many-to-one relationship

```
class Author(model):
    name = TextField()

class Book(model):
    year = IntegerField()
    author = ForeignKey(Author)
```

you can easily filter from the "many" side. Eg, keep only the books whose author satisfies some condition

```
books.objects.filter(author__name__like='...')
```

How can I, from the `Author` side, keep (for *each* author) only the books that satisfy a condition? Eg. is there something like

```
Author.related_filter(book__year__gt>1800)
```

that would produce something like

```
select * from 
author join book on ...
where book.year > 1800
```

??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) with a custom [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) object:

```
authors = Author.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('book_set', queryset=Book.objects.filter(year>1800), to_attr='modern_books')
)

for author in authors:
    for book in author.modern_books.all():
        # do stuff
```

This should result in two queries total, so not quite the single SQL statement you are looking for, but the ORM's built-in way to fetch filtered related objects.

Comment: thanks. If I just wanted to count the `modern_books` per author, is that efficient, or is there a more appropriate way??